# Get a notification when a facebook page post is made

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I follow a facebook page which has some interesting posts and they post regularly. I want to write a python script that gives me a notification whenever the page posts something. Is there a way I can accomplish this in Python?

I have searched a bit, seems like graph API is the way to go. However, all the tutorials I have seen online give a way to **scrape** some data or get post information. I do not seem to figure out a way to detect when a new post is made.

How should I accomplish this task?

Comment: Facebook has webhooks to get apps notified about changes - but you would need admin access to the page to be able to use those. And even if you just regularly polled yourself, you would need to submit your app for approval of the Public Page Content Access feature first - and I think it’s rather doubtful you get this use case approved.

Answer (score 0):

Notifications for changes or new posts can only be made with Webhooks - which are only available if you manage the Page. Scraping is not allowed on Facebook, so there is no way to get notifications for Pages you do not manage.

You could only check with the API on a regular basis, but you would need Public Page Content Access for that, and you may have a problem with API limits if there are many Page Posts or Pages you want to check.

Comment: Is it still true? I think the notification settings have changed a lot in recent months for the facebook app. I'm currently trying different settings to see if I get notified instantly when posts are made to a group I follow...

Comment: t o be honest, i do not know for sure as i did not use the notifications api and webhooks in a while, but i would be surprised if it would be different now. getting notified instantly is exactly what webhooks are about though.